# XSym: not found while executing binary in Docker on Windows

Tags: typescript, docker

I am using Docker on windows.

Error:

```
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install -g
 ---> Running in ec6582e10f69
+ lfg-auth@1.0.0
added 1 package in 0.437s
Removing intermediate container ec6582e10f69
 ---> f2b9a25a51a3
Step 5/5 : RUN npm run build-tsc
 ---> Running in 6321ac31e370

> lfg-auth@1.0.0 build-tsc /app
> tsc

/app/node_modules/.bin/tsc: line 1: XSym: not found
/app/node_modules/.bin/tsc: line 2: 0021: not found
/app/node_modules/.bin/tsc: line 3: 8cbd85238d8fbeb66a0afc1d79bcd880: not found
/app/node_modules/.bin/tsc: line 4: ../typescript/bin/tsc: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! lfg-auth@1.0.0 build-tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lfg-auth@1.0.0 build-tsc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-17T09_27_42_522Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'auth' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build-tsc' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.15.0-alpine

ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g
RUN npm run build-tsc
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build-tsc": "tsc",
    ...
  },
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  }
```

If I try to run the same command inside a terminal in the docker container it works perfectly. Using docker-compose if I put it in the command field it also works fine.

Answer (score 9):

I see this problem with `react-scripts build` when I have my Windows `node_modules/` folder mounted inside the Linux container.  Most likely, you ran `npm install` in Windows then copied `node_modules/` into your image on build, or you have your local project folder mounted as a Docker volume.  Either way, you are trying to run a Windows executable on Linux and it blows up.

Technically it happens because content of binary file `/app/node_modules/.bin/tsc` looks like

```
XSym
0021
8cbd85238d8fbeb66a0afc1d79bcd880
../typescript/bin/tsc
```

You should be able to work around the build-time issue by adding `node_modules/` to your `.dockerignore` file.

If, like me, you later mount the local project directory inside the container for development purposes, you will still have to throw away the `node_modules/` folder manually and run `npm install` again from inside the container.

Comment: To avoid having to npm install inside the container, mount a `/src/node_modules` (or wherever it's located inside your container). This will mount the node_modules already inside the image ABOVE your mounted source code. This does require you docker build each time you change dependencies, but that's fairly normal anyways.

This process gets even simpler with docker-compose since you can easily mount both your source and the image's node_modules there. Just use `docker-compose up --build -V` when dependencies change.

Comment: Agreed, I encountered the "XSym" error on a strapi app after trying to run `npm run strapi develop`. This is because I transferred all my work from macOS to Ubuntu and so it seems the binaries were not compatible here (especially since I noticed that one of the dependencies was `fsevents` a mac only required package). So, I simply deleted node_modules, ran `npm install` and it generated binaries for linux, worked like a charm.